# Algorithm for assignment of css categories in act-as-taggable-on gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, act-as-taggable-on

I am using act-as-taggable-on gem. Trying to understand how tags are allocated between 4 css categories. As in this example: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-cloud-calculations.

What is the algorithm that decides the number of tags allocated to each css category? And can I change the number of css categories from 4 to 6 for example, can I do this:

`<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4 css5 css6)) do |tag, css_class| %> 
  <%= link_to tag.name, { :action => :tag, :id => tag.name }, :class => css_class %> 
<% end %>`

Basically, how is the assignment of css categories distributed? I’ve looked through the documentation and have yet to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tag_cloud` method source code reads:

```
def tag_cloud(tags, classes)
  return [] if tags.empty?
    max_count = tags.sort_by(&:taggings_count).last.taggings_count.to_f

  tags.each do |tag|
    index = ((tag.taggings_count / max_count) * (classes.size - 1))
      yield tag, classes[index.nan? ? 0 : index.round]
    end
  end
end
```

Which means that you are able to pass as many classes as you need. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/8e64c3d4a81cfbb8af621228eae36a65c1f94501/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tags_helper.rb).